# Aligning subfigures and subcaptions

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I am using 'tabular' option to display the subfigures and subcaptions. Following is my code.

```
    \begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=4.3cm, height=4.3cm]{NITRA_pep_inp} \\[\abovecaptionskip]
    \small (a) Input peppers image
    \label{cari1}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=4.3cm, height=4.3cm]{NITRA_pep_out_20} \\[\abovecaptionskip]
    \small (b) Reconstructed Peppers Image \\
    \small M=20, PSNR = 30.9370 dB \\
    \label{caro1}
\end{tabular}
\vskip\baselineskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=4.3cm, height=4.3cm]{NITRA_pep_inp} \\[\abovecaptionskip]
    \small (a) Input frame (eg) (Akiyo series)
    \label{aki1}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=4.3cm, height=4.3cm]{NITRA_pep_out_20} \\[\abovecaptionskip]
    \small (b) Reconstructed frame (eg) (Akiyo series) \\
    \small M = 20, PSNR = 34.7404 dB
    \label{akio2}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Reconstructed images and video frames using NITRA with number of measurements and their corresponding PSNR in dB}
\label{NITRAres1}
    \end{figure}
```

The resultant image that I get is as follows:
[image: The resultant picture]

How should I change the code such that the subfigures and subcaptions are aligned properly? 'Subfigure' and 'subcaption' doesnot work well for me and that is why I chose 'tabular'.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Simply replace all `\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}` directives with `\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}`. I suspect this question has been asked before, so I'm not posting this comment as a separate, new answer.

Comment: Wow.... This worked out perfectly. Thank you so much. Yet, the uneven gaps between the images of the two rows remain the same.

Comment: I solved this problem using \hspace. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Could you provide more detail as to why "'Subfigure' and 'subcaption' doesnot work well for me"? Are you maybe using a special document class? Please advise.

Comment: I have used the following code with subfigure: `\begin{figure*}%
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}{.4\columnwidth}
  %\centering
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{NITRA_pep_inp.png}%
  \caption{a) Peppers}%
  \label{subfig:1}%
 \end{subfigure}\hfill%
 \begin{subfigure}{.4\columnwidth}
  %\centering
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{NITRA_pep_out_20.png}%
  \caption{b) Reconstructed image}%
  \label{subfig:2}%
 \end{subfigure}
 \caption{Total}
 \label{key}
\end{figure*}`

Comment: I have used 'subfigure' package. But, I get errors like 'Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{subfigure}{.4\columnwidth}' and 'Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \begin{subfigure}{.4\columnwidth}'. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Which document class do you use? Please advise.

Comment: It is actually my university's thesis format. The class specified is this: `\documentclass[13 pt,a4paper]{authesis}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing the four `\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}` directives with `\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}` will solve the immediate (vertical) alignment issue. However, the four `\label` instructions inside the `tabular` environments will continue to have no effect as they're not associated with any counters that are being incremented via a mechanism such as, say, `\refstepcounter`.

I therefore suggest you (a) load the `subcaption` package (which works fine with most document classes, by the way), (b) replace the `tabular` environments with `subfigure` environments, and (c) use `\caption` directives inside each `subfigure`. That way, subfigures can also be cross-referenced individually.

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{4.5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth]{NITRA_pep_inp} 
\caption{Input peppers image}
\label{cari1}
\end{subfigure}
\qquad % some horizontal space
\begin{subfigure}[t]{4.5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth]{NITRA_pep_out_20}
\caption{Reconstructed Peppers Image, M=20, PSNR = 30.9370 dB} 
\label{caro1}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\begin{subfigure}[t]{4.5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth]{NITRA_pep_inp}
\caption{Input frame (Akiyo series)}
\label{aki1}
\end{subfigure} 
\qquad % some horizontal space
\begin{subfigure}[t]{4.5cm}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth]{NITRA_pep_out_20}
\caption{Reconstructed frame (Akiyo series), M = 20, PSNR = 34.7404 dB} 
\label{akio2}
\end{subfigure}

% caption for overall figure env.:
\caption{Reconstructed images and video frames using NITRA with 
number of measurements and their corresponding PSNR in dB}
\label{NITRAres1} 
\end{figure}

A cross-reference to figure \ref{akio2}.
\end{document}
```